# Identity disappears from bearer token after an hour

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am working on a multi-tenant solution with Azure AD with web apps and a web api. The web app uses OpenIdConnect to retrieve a bearer token (which is cached in Azure Redis Cache), which is used in Angular to get JSON from the web api. User impersonation is used between the web app and web api (set up in Azure AD applications).

**Problem:**

This works fine for about an hour, then the Identity suddenly disappears on the web api side. If I refresh the web app, I see that the page is redirected to the Microsoft login page, but no action is required since the user is just redirected back to the web app and everything works again. As far as I can see, the web app uses the same bearer token when it fails and after the refresh (same expire time) when it works again. AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilent works in both scenarios.

I have tried to increase a lot of different timeouts, but nothing has helped. I have also disabled all but bearer token authentication on the web api. I do not understand why the identity disapears and why it helps to refresh the client. Any ideas? :)

**Additional info**

This is how the RequestContext.Principal.Identity looks for about an hour after login or a refresh (on the web api):

[image]

And this is after about an hour, which causes authentication to fail:

[image]

Some of the code changes I have tried out:

In web api HttpConfiguration:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(
            new HostAuthenticationFilter(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions().AuthenticationType));
```

This changed the unauthenticated principal from WindowsPrincipal to ClaimsPrincipal, but it still fails after an hour.

```
WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions BackChannelTimeout set to 5 days. Still fails
```

In the web app web.config:

```
sessionState timeout="525600" for RedisSessionStateProvider. Still fails
```

In the web app owin auth process, increased timespan and added sliding expiration. Still fails:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieHttpOnly = true
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Constants.CommonAuthority,
                UseTokenLifetime = false
```

**Update:**

To flesh out some details: We have a hybrid MVC Angular web application. Many MVC menu items which each lead to an Angular "single page application" for that menu item. MVC is used for routing, authentication and authorization. In addition, additional claims is retrieved and appended to the current principal server side. The menu items are MVC controllers that are protected with the Authorized and ClaimsPrincipalPermission attributes. Since the web page will run in Azure, we changed the default sessionProvider to Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider. Only the MVC server side talks to this redis session cache.  The bearer token (not refresh token) is shared with Angular through an Authorized protected MVC controller, which is then stored in the browser session storage (similar to adal.js use of localstorage?) Angular gets JSON content from a CORS enabled API that lives in a separate domain from the MVC app. The API and MVC app also belong to two different Azure AD applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be crossing flows here. If you are making calls from JavaScript, you should obtain the token in the client - something like http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/.
Redirect based authentication flows in which the outcome is a cookie are not well suited for scenarios in which you call API via JavaScript. Furthermore, if I understood correctly you are obtaining a token as a private client and then sharing it out of band (redis cache) with a public client running inside a user agent. That's a no-no from the security perspective.

That said: if you are really really set in keeping up with your current route, I suggest taking a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/ for achieving full separation between your web UX and web API routes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This has been a thorn in my side for many months now. It seems like adal.js will be our solution for the future, but not until it matures (only a few internal users that have the problem and they can live with it for now). But, when we do use adal.js, will it work in our hybrid MVC angular application (see Update in question)? Is it possible to first authenticate using OpenConnectId and MVC and then adal.js will just work since it discovers that there is an Azure AD cookie present? And how should we get adal.js to initiate authentication if routing is handled in MVC?

Comment: Also,  to ensure that I avoid security no-nos, can you verify that our use of RedisSessionStateProvider to cache tokens server side(see Update in question) is a security problem?

Comment: The hybrid arch you have might work, but you'd have to do some custom work. That is especially the case if you put pages and API in the same application/domain. Why not having everything as a SPA?

Comment: About the cache. Token acquisition should only take place through known protocols, given that they are threat modeled and proven. Here you are adding your own leg to the flow, in essence extending the protocol. That often brings to unintended consequences. What makes this worse is that you acquire the token for a confidential client, which can be bestowed app-level rights, and pass it on for reuse to the worst kind of public clients, a user agent one. In an ideal world the JS client would acquire its own token.

Comment: We started the project in January 2014 an at that time, it seemed that ADAL with OpenConnectId in MVC server side was the way to go for Azure AD authentication (based on examples and VS2013 templates). Still, we wanted to work with Angular on UI, thus the hybrid was born. Also, it was easier to use claims for authorization in MVC and limit access to menu elements through controller attributes. I have still not seen any examples of claims based authorization in Angular, but I have not looked very hard lately. Do you know of any? If we started the project post adal.js, it would be SPA :)

Comment: On to the cache. If I understand you correctly, it seems like both sharing the token with JS and using Redis as session cache is a problem and I don't get that. I have no problem understanding that sharing the token with JS is a no-no, and as soon as adal.js is more stable I will update our code so JS will acquire its own token. But what is the problem with redis as a session state provider used by AuthenticationContext to cache tokens only on server side? The NaiveSessionCache example will not work in a multi instance azure environment. Or have I misunderstood something. It happens :)

Comment: Redis is not a problem per se. Getting a token as a protected client and passing it back to a public client is the crux of the issue. If you are a public client, there are flows for you for getting a token without reusing tokens issued to others

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I look forward to adal.js :)